# .NET Core Web API application not debugging from Visual Studio 2015

Tags: .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I have a .NET Core Web API project using version 1.0.0-preview2-003131. Using VS 2015 I am able to compile the project without a problem, but when I try debugging the application I am receiving the following errors:

The program '[13416] dotnet.exe' has exited with code -2147450749 (0x80008083).
The program '[12920] iisexpress.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

I am also able to create a new web api project using this same version and it works fine so it has to be project specific. Any ideas?

Comment: Try running `dotnet run` from the project folder - You may well see a stack trace.

Comment: Note that you are running a version that has been out of support for quite a while. Preview versions are not supposed to be bug free.